# Media player buttons in volume control

Tags: settings, music

What's the deal with music player for windows phone 7.5. Whenever I stop playing music and return back, the mini player starts showing on the lock screen and disappears automatically after some time. Why does this appear , is it supposed to be ??

Please tell me how does this work. I am using Nokia lumia 710 with Tango OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. It will disappear if you unlock your phone whilst no media is playing, and start another app. If the phone is at the lockscreen, and you tap the volume control, the mini-player will show again, along with the volume controls.

Comment: Does this mean the music player application is only suspended even though by pressing the back arrow you have exited it?

Comment: I believe the mini-player is provided by the system, and not the app.

Comment: @Arabella The music player is a system app, so it's built-in to the OS. You can "exit" it by pressing back, but it's designed to always be accessible in the background (from the lock screen or volume controls), if you have anything in your "now playing" playlist.

Comment: @sidran32 Thanks for the info